# Append to visual block only on specific lines

Tags: vim

Lets say i have the following text.

```
this.is.some.text
this.is.emos.text
this.is.some.text
this.is.emos.text
```

I want to edit this text in 'Visual Block' mode so that the text looks as follows.

```
this.is.some.text
this.is.emos_suffix.text
this.is.some.text
this.is.emos_suffix.text
```

It should work like this:

- Select a visual block
- If the visual block contains emos append '_suffix' to the visual
  block (Just like the 'A' command would do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only native way to accomplish that *from visual-block mode or any other visual mode* is to use a substitution:

```
:'<,'>s/emos/&_suffix<CR>
```

where…

- you press `:`,
- Vim inserts the range `'<,'>` for you, meaning "from the fist selected line, `:help '<`, through the last selected line, `:help` '>`,
- `s/emos/&_suffix` substitutes every first occurrence of `emos` on each line of the given range with itself, `:help s/\&`, followed by `_suffix`.

Visual selection is often an unnecessary step and, in this case, visual-block mode is totally useless because `A` or `I` is going to operate on every line of the selection anyway.

Another method:

```
/emos/e<CR>
a_suffix<Esc>
n
.
```

Another one:

```
/emos<CR>
cgn<C-r>"
_suffix<Esc>
.
```

Another one, assuming the cursor is on the first line of your sample:

```
:,'}s/emos/&_suffix<CR>
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. I was experimenting in the same direction but was hoping there is a more elegant solution. The main problem is that theres no way i know of to access the visual block in ex mode. The :g command can execute normal commands on lines like so ":'<,'>g/emos/normal A_suffix<CR>" where 'A' is append to line end. So my first experiments looked like ":'<,'>g/emos/visual A_suffix<CR>" where i hoped the 'A' command is executed in the visual block context.